# Spot any error in the proof.

Tags: proof-writing, field-theory, soft-question, solution-verification

I was learning to write proofs from this [proof guide pdf](http://eugeniacheng.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/cheng-proofguide.pdf). In that at last there was an example of a proof and I was supposed to find anything wrong in that(maybe not the mathematics involved but the structure in which it is represented or anything else). I was unable to spot anything wrong in that. Following is a screenshot of the problem and proof:

[image]

Kindly spot anything wrong with this proof.

Comment: It's written in sans-serif?

Comment: +1 I'm not an expert in field theory proofs, so it is plausible that a subtlety could escape me.  Beyond that, proof looks good.

Comment: Strictly speaking, $-y = (-1)y$ and $0\cdot x = 0$ can be proven from the field axioms, but it is not in the field axioms themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how annoying you want to get. The proof implicitly uses the associativity of addition a bunch without naming it. I also agree with player3236 in the comments that $-y = (-1)y$ and $(0)x = 0$ can be quickly proven from, but are not actually part of, the field theory axioms.